# Production Dynamodb with Operations Data

Tags: validation, amazon-dynamodb

We have 2 AWS accounts; dev and prod.  In the dev account, we have 2 identically structured DynamoDB tables; one for QA, and the other for CI.  In prod we have another copy of the table, but just for our prod data.  Data gets pushed on to an SQS queue, which is consumed by a service and put into DynamoDB.

I have just found out that our ops team, whilst smoke testing gated feature releases, put Operations (test) data on to the SQS queue that ends up in the prod table.  My initial reaction was that this is bad practice and only prod data should be in the prod database, but the counter argument was that it was needed to fully test end-to-end that everything's working as expected.

Is it an acceptable practice to put test data in prod tables under these circumstances?  I would expect that once the test data has served its purpose, that is to check the release process, it would be removed.  Are there any other concerns with this approach?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a third account for PreProd and use cross-region replication to maintain a read replica of your table in the prod account. Otherwise, your production application would be responsible for discerning between data that actually belongs in prod and test data.